# Macbook can not access personal hotspot

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, wifi, tethering

I have a Macbook Pro with Mac OS 12.6.5, and an iPhone 6+ with iOS 12.5.7

On my iPhone, I have turned on "Personal Hotspot", and assigned a password to it.

I can access this Personal Hotspot from i.e. my iPad, i.e. I can access the Internet in this way.

On the Macbook, I can see my personal hotspot in the menu bar among the available networks.

When I click on this personal hotspot item in the menu bar, I would expect to be asked for the password. Instead after maybe half a minute, a message pops up: "Failed to enable Personal Hotspot .... Check to see if the device is turned on and in range of your computer".

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reset Network Settings

On your iPhone, go to **Settings** > **General** > **Transfer or Reset** [Device] > **Reset**, then tap **Reset Network Settings**. And try again.